# What are the possible ways of integrating(on chain) a custom smart contract with 0x?

Tags: solidity, 0x

Dont want to depend upon web api based fetching quotes for swapping, rather swap completely on chain.

But the 0x doc mentions:-
[image: 0x d0c]

Answer (score 1):

The docs are saying that you can use directly the api response on a web send transaction call as they are doing here on this following example: https://github.com/0xProject/0x-starter-project/blob/master/src/scenarios/fill_0x_api_swap.ts. However you can call directly the smartcontracts using the tools provided by 0x, you have here an example how to fill a limit order directly without the need of ZRX API: https://github.com/0xProject/0x-starter-project/blob/master/src/scenarios/fill_erc20_limit_order.ts